# ModelMapper: how to handle null values for enums

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am trying to map one object type to another using ModelMapper.
I have defined the following mapping in my PropertyMap implementation:

```
map().getExtended().setIncludeMaskType(MaskType.fromValue(source.getExtendedPollingType().getMaskSettings().getIncludeMask().getMaskType()));
```

The problem is that the source type method call `source.getExtendedPollingType().getMaskSettings().getIncludeMask().getMaskType()`
returns String while the destination type accepts a `MaskType` enum

Therefore I am using `MaskType.fromValue()` to convert the String to enum. 
The problem is that value of fails with `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` since this is source method call basically returns null during configuration.

So how should I handle this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK seems that the correct way to do this is with using a Converter:

```
using((MappingContext<String, MaskType> context) -> {
    return MaskType.fromValue(context.getSource());
}).
map(source.getExtendedPollingType().getMaskSettings().getIncludeMask().getMaskType()).getExtended().setIncludeMaskType(null);
```

This is explained in more details here:
https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/20